# Cloud Functions and Firestore: Using Promise.all() to track multiple documetn modifications

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise, google-cloud-functions

I use a callable Cloud function for creating a new user. For this user, multiple documents in Cloud Firestore are created.

I do not want to store only parts of the data, if one promise (document creation fails), but completely undo the registration, so I use `Promise.all(documentCreationPromisses)`

So my question is if it is still possible that some documents are created and others are not, although I use Promise.all() ?

Comment: Yes because you still create all of them at once. `Promise.all` will return a rejected promise if one of the operations fails but that doesn't change the fact that all of the operations get executed (successfully or not). It would be best to use `allSettled` instead, and then you would check if they were all successful or not - it not, you would go and delete the documents that were successfully uploaded, to undo the partial upload. (The reason that it won't be enough to do that on a failed `Promise.all` is that you may get the error before some of the other docs have finished uploading.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all()` returns a promise that tells you if all of the other promises succeeded, or if any one of them failed.  It can certainly resolve with a partial set of successes, and there was a failure, you would have to check each individual promise to find out which ones succeeded or failed.

If you are modifying a bunch of documents in Firestore, and you require that all of the modifications either fully succeed, otherwise nothing happens (a full rollback), then you should use a [batch write or transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).  With a batch writes and transactions, everything must succeed, or the entire batch fails.  The single returned promise from that batch will tell you what happened.